# In Matlab how do I concatenate the arrays stored in entirely different matrices when the matrix has at least 3 dimensions?

Tags: matlab

E.g. I want to combine all the data in ans(:,:,8) with ans(:,:,9) and so on...

Comment: Concatenate along which dimension?

Comment: The question and title don't quite match.  The title talks about different matrices, the question offers a single example of a rank-3 array.  Do you mean that you want to reduce a rank-3 array to a rank-2 array by applying some function to all the elements with the same first-two indices ?  Whatever you want, more explanation please, and an example input and required output.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see [heterogenous cat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous.cat.html?searchHighlight=cat) and [Normal concatenation](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)

In different directions, try [horzcat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) and [vertcat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html)